# How to determine the alignment an object would like

Tags: c++, memory, memory-alignment

I have a previously allocated chunk of memory that I want to interpret in-place as a `struct`.  How could I determine the memory address within the chunk that has the friendliest alignment for the `struct`?

Just need to know the mechanism for determining what byte boundary a given `struct` would work best within, basically.

```
// psuedo-code

struct Object{
    int    theseMembersCould;
    double beAnything;
    char   itsJustData[69];
}

// a chunk of previously allocated memory that I want to use
std::vector<uint8> block;
block.resize(1024);

uint32 byteBoundary = ????;  // <-- this is what I want to discover

// math to get the nearest addr on the boundary (assumes byteBoundary will be POW2)
uint32 alignmentOffset= (byteBoundary - (block.data() & byteBoundary-1u)) & byteBoundary-1u;

Object * obj = new (block.data() + alignmentOffset) Object;
obj->itsJustData = "used as if it were a normal object beyond this point";
```

Comment: C++11 and later, look up the `alignof` operator, `alignas` specifier, and `std::aligned_storage` type trait.   Plenty of information, with examples, on various C++ reference sites.    In combination, they can most likely be used to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) operator will tell you the alignment required by a type. For example `const auto byteBoundary = alignof(Object);`.

Consider using [`std::aligned_storage`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage) if you need to create aligned raw memory. You will also need to use [placement `new`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/what-uses-are-there-for-placement-new) to properly being the lifetime of the `Object` you are trying to use `block` as.

Comment: @AnneQuinn Remember that by using `new`, your object will not be automatically destroyed. But using `delete` would also be problematic, as you are not suppose to release the memory like you would normally. You need to manually call your object's destructor when you are done with it with `obj->~Object();`.

Answer (score 2):

Firs off, you attempted use of `reinterpret_cast` is incorrect, as it leads to undefined behavior due to strict aliasing rule violation. Instead, you should use placement new.

To properly align your struct, you can use `std::align` together with `std::alignof`.